# C# UdpClient.Send get's slower and slower

Tags: c#, udp

I want to send a bunch of data with low latency to another device using UDP.

This is a short snippet that reproduces the problem:

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(9000);
        IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, 7000);

        new Thread(() =>
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1922];
            while (true)
            {          
                stopwatch.Start();
                udpClient.Send(buffer, buffer.Length, endPoint);
                stopwatch.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Sending took " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms"); // stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds gets higher and higher
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        }).Start();
    }
```

The buffer has the same size everytime (in the loop) and the packets are sent every 10 ms...normally.

But approx. every 300ms it takes 1 additional millisecond to send so after a short time it takes already 1 minute to send a packet.

What is the problem there and how do I fix it?

Comment: It looks to me as if the question is too broad to answer since your question is concerned of specific rather than general case which may be caused by means other than those were provided in your code example. Please provide more detail.

Comment: I have edited the post, there is a code snippet now, that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your measurement: you're not resetting your stopwatch anywhere.  Instead of calling the `stopwatch.Start()` method, call the `Restart()` method instead.

[Stopwatch Class (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx)

> Restart() : Stops time interval measurement, resets the elapsed time to zero, and starts measuring elapsed time.

```
while (true)
{          
    stopwatch.Restart();
    udpClient.Send(buffer, buffer.Length, endPoint);
    stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Sending took " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms"); 
    Thread.Sleep(10);
}
```

Comment: Wow, I feel so stupid right now, I was worrying all the time about the UDPClient but never looked at the Stopwatch. Thank you!